# Passing a message from a listener

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have an event that I'm creating in my model's beforeSave function:

```
  public function beforeSave(Event $event, Entity $entity) {
    $event = new Event('Model.Transaction.createTransaction', $this, [
      'transaction' => $entity
    ]);
    $this->eventManager()->dispatch($event);

    if ($event->isStopped()) {
      return FALSE;
    }
  }
```

Which is grabbed by a Listener I have created:

```
public function implementedEvents() {
  return [
    'Model.Transaction.createTransaction' => 'createHistorical'
  ];
}
```

This all works fine. What I was wondering is if there's any way to pass a message back to the model where the event was registered. So that if there's a failure or something, I can pass a message back to the model and add it to the errors to be displayed on the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return a value from the callback method (`createHistorical` in your case) which would be accessible using `$event->result` after dispatching is done.